# Запрос на поиск mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Структура таблицы `regpro`

idsoobsh

date

tipproish

---

Дамп данных таблицы regpro

1|  2011-11-01 18:38:26|    ebistvo|

2|  2011-11-02 10:41:47|    razboi|

3|  2011-11-04 10:41:47|    toto|

```
SELECT * FROM regpro WHERE date = '2011-11-01 18:38:26'
```

Это простой поиск по дате , а как сделать поиск с определенной даты по определенную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT * FROM regpro WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-12-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Храните дату в формате timestamp (время в секундах), формируйте дату с помощью [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), и запрос будет типа

```
SELECT * FROM regpro WHERE date >= '123454784876' AND date <='123454884976'
```

для разбора даты используйте [getdate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)